# Twain device (scanner) control in .net?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, twain

I want to scan a number of papers through .net .I found dynamsoft and atalasoft but both are expensive iam looking for opensource Twain component that support chrome and IE

Comment: Web browsers do not support Twain scanning on their own. You will definitely need some sort of component or plug-in with higher level permissions to be installed on the PC to communicate with the Twain source (scanner) and deliver the scanned images to the browser-based application. Using twain requires access to the local hardware which has traditionally been unavailable to web developers.
There has been at least one open source attempt (http://twainx.sourceforge.net/) but it only works with MS IE, and only with older versions of it.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for sophisticated commercial SDKs, why don't you make it yourself? Do you know how to implement a desktop TWAIN app in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

THis is a bit late, but there is a free ware solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/web_twain.aspx)